# Issues with volume mounting with Docker-compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

Whenever I make changes to any controllers (or files in general) within my rails application, I can't see them show up until I run `docker-compose down` follow by `docker-compose build` and finally `docker-compose up`. Essentially, I have to completely rebuild the project and run up again for my changes to take effect.

The only changes that show up are changes made to views.

My current process to get the environment setup is:

1. cd into directory that holds the Dockerfile
2. Run docker-compose build (if not already built)
3. Run docker-compose up

What am I missing? I'm using Docker for Windows.

My docker-compose.yml is as follows:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: dev
        POSTGRES_USER: user
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM ruby:2.3.1
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
ADD Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install
ADD . /myapp
```

Comment: Can you add also the Dockerfile?

Comment: Sure! It's been added. @Lauri

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting volume in your docker-compose file ?

https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/compose/yml/#volumes

`- HOST_PATH:CONTAINER_PATH`

```
web:
  volumes:
    - ./src:/app/user/src
```

Comment: Yup, I tried adding volume but that didn't seem to work. I've added my Dockerfile if that helps at all.

Comment: Strange! From what I understand, in your specific compose file, volumes should mount your project directory to `/myapp` so you can modify the code without having to rebuild the image.

Comment: In my projects I use webpack which watches for changes in my source files and rebuilds. I am not familiar with rails but does `bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'` rebuild your project on change of source files? That could be the issue. Does that command only build the first time ? Then that would make sense you would only see the changes on restart of docker compose.

Comment: That command would simply start up the rails server and typically only needs to be called once. As long as the server is running, the app and its changes should in theory work as well.

Comment: In theory it should work for you as expected. It looks like you are using the docker compose rails guide as a starting point, so you think it would work. Maybe try deleting your images and containers and running docker compose again?

Comment: So I've narrowed it down a little bit, but I'm still at a loss, haha. It looks like some files are being mounted properly, but not all. Of the files that are actually being mounted, they do work correctly and reflect the code changes I make. For whatever reason though, only 1/3 of the required files in the directory are being mounted?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create path in Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir /myapp
```

if you mount it in docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
  - .:/myapp
```

Please remove also line:

```
ADD . /myapp
```

I think this is the issue -

> The ADD instruction copies new files, directories or remote file URLs
>   from  and adds them to the filesystem of the container at the
>   path .
>   (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/add)

So it looks like this command copy files just once instead of mounting them.